# widget does not apears on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, ipywidgets

i am trying to use the widget button, here is my code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

button = widgets.Button(description='Hello')
display(button)
```

then in the output i get

```
Button(description='Hello', style=ButtonStyle())
```

i already try this:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix
```

and this is what i get:

```
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK
```

i also tried to

```
pip uninstall ipywidgets
pip install ipywidgets
```

Comment: I have the same issue. My code works perfectly in Google Colab, but in Jupyter notebook I get a text representation of the widget instead of the actual widget. Textarea in my case.

P.S. OMG! I created a new virtualenv, started Jupyter, and it displays the Textarea now :| Previously I started Jupyter without the virtualenv.